# snippets with autmoatic date time in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to do snippets (TODO,CHANGED,NOTE,FIXME...) than includes date and time automaticaly

I don't know how todo it with only 1 snippet (1 keystroke)

This is what I'm doing now for "TODO", what I have:

1- Snippet: `todo.sublime-snippet` file than insert `${TM_COMMENT_START}TODO: ${1}${TM_COMMENT_END}` after type `todo`

2- pluggin: than inserts date + time:

```
import datetime, getpass
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class AddTimeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "contents": "%s" %  "("+datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")+" - "+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")+"h) "  } )
```

3- Keybinding to execute the plugin:

```
{ "keys": ["t","t"], "command": "add_time" }
```

So now, I first type `todo` to insert ***// TODO:*** and then I type `tt` to insert **30/03/2017 18:12h**

And I woluld like to type only `todo`

I think the clue is in **add in the plugin the environment variable** TM_COMMENT_START and TM_COMMENT_END, but how?